# Tangent Plane on a surface

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I'm trying to graph the tangent plane on the unit sphere at the point `(1, \pi/3,\pi/4)`. I'm new to tikz, so I'm unsure how to edit the graphs other users have made with the planes for each point. Here's the current graph of a sphere I have:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        axis equal,
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        zlabel = {$z$},
        ticks=none,
        enlargelimits=0.3,
        view/h=45,
        scale uniformly strategy=units only,
    ]
    \addplot3[%
        opacity = 0.5,
        surf,
        z buffer = sort,
        samples = 21,
        variable = \u,
        variable y = \v,
        domain = 0:180,
        y domain = 0:360,
    ]
    ({cos(u)*sin(v)}, {sin(u)*sin(v)}, {cos(v)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

What's the easiest way to add the tangent plane to the graph? Do I have to create 4 nodes and then fill the rectangle they make? Or is it possible to create a plane based on the span of two vectors originating from that point? Any and all help/explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a style that inserts a plane at a point that is spanned by two vectors.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tangent plane/.style args={at #1 with vectors #2 and #3}{%
insert path={#1 --  ($#1+($#2-(0,0,0)$)$) --  ($#1+($#2-(0,0,0)$)+($#3-(0,0,0)$)$) 
-- ($#1+($#3-(0,0,0)$)$) -- cycle}}]
    \begin{axis}[%
        axis equal,
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        zlabel = {$z$},
        ticks=none,
        enlargelimits=0.3,
        view/h=45,
        scale uniformly strategy=units only,
    ]
    \addplot3[%
        opacity = 0.5,
        surf,
        z buffer = sort,
        samples = 21,
        variable = \u,
        variable y = \v,
        domain = 0:180,
        y domain = 0:360,
    ]
    ({cos(u)*sin(v)}, {sin(u)*sin(v)}, {cos(v)});
    \draw[fill=white,fill opacity=0.4,
    tangent plane=at {(-0.5,-0.5,1)} with vectors {(1,0,0)} and {(0,1,0)}];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The mandatory animation:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{tangent plane/.style args={at #1 with vectors #2 and #3}{%
    insert path={#1 --  ($#1+($#2-(0,0,0)$)$) --  ($#1+($#2-(0,0,0)$)+($#3-(0,0,0)$)$) 
    -- ($#1+($#3-(0,0,0)$)$) -- cycle}}}
\foreach \Angle in {90,85,...,0}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis,
        axis equal,
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        zlabel = {$z$},
        ticks=none,
        enlargelimits=0.3,
        view/h=45,
        scale uniformly strategy=units only,
    ]
    \addplot3[%
        opacity = 0.5,
        surf,
        z buffer = sort,
        samples = 21,
        variable = \u,
        variable y = \v,
        domain = 0:180,
        y domain = 0:360,
    ]
    ({cos(u)*sin(v)}, {sin(u)*sin(v)}, {cos(v)});
    \draw[overlay,fill=white,fill opacity=0.4,
    tangent plane=at {({cos(\Angle)-0.5*sin(\Angle)},-0.5,{sin(\Angle)})} with 
    vectors {({sin(\Angle)},0,{-cos(\Angle)})} and {(0,1,0)}];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting, as usual. I believe two of the `\edef`s can be simplified a bit, because `\edef` doesn't expand `#1`, `#2`, etc. They are just *replaced* as for `\def` (that is, after the expansion done by `\edef`). These work for me: first, the `\edef` in `\VecAdd` can be replaced with `\def`; second: `/utils/exec=\def\temp{\VecAdd#1+#2->\myvecOne XXX}`, third: as is because of `\myvecOne`, and fourth: `\def\temp{\VecAdd#1+#3->\myvecThree XXX}`.

Comment: @frougon Yes, thanks! As you say, it becomes less symmetric if one replaces some `\edef`s with `\def`s.  But I completely switched gears now, the code is now more powerful in that is also works with symbolic coordinates and is much shorter. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for showing yet another way! These `-(0,0,0)` are black magic to me, but since I haven't read about 3D handling in TikZ yet... maybe this is a way to trigger the 3D to 2D-canvas projection?

Comment: @frougon The `-(0,0,0)` are just because the origin of the 3d coordinate system, `(0,0,0)`, and the origin of the Ti*k*Z coordinate system, call it `(0,0)`, do not coincide. And yes, there are such projections, they are can be obtained from `canvas is ... plane` of the 3d library that is explained in section **40 Three Dimensional Drawing Library** of the pgfmanual v 3.1.3.

Comment: @marmot Can you explain "the mandatory animation"? Thanks in advance

Comment: @jpayansomet That's just a joke. The purpose is only to show that it works, i.e. you can attach the tangent plane at any point.

Comment: @marmot I understand the joke but it's very nice and I'd like to repeat it

Comment: @jpayansomet If you repeat a joke typically people do not laugh about it any more. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Sorry but this time is the first time I have laughed with that joke